# Can there two leaq instructions be merged into one?

Tags: assembly, x86, att

There are some ATT assembly examples from Computer Systems: a Programmer's Perspective. Here is one:

> array element A[i][j] can be copied to register %eax by the
>   following code:
>
> ```
> (A in %rdi, i in %rsi, and j in %rdx)
>
> 1 leaq (%rsi,%rsi,2), %rax Compute 3i
> 2 leaq (%rdi,%rax,4), %rax Compute x_A + 12i
> 3 movl (%rax,%rdx,4), %eax Read from M[x_A + 12i + 4j]
> ```

Can the first two instructions be merged into

```
leaq (%rdi,%rsi,12), %rax
```

since it also computes x_A + 12i?

Why does the book choose to write two instructions instead? The same thing happens in other examples.

Thanks.

Comment: See _Figure 3-11. Offset (or Effective Address) Computation_ in the basic architecture manual.

Answer (score 1):

No, only the scale factors 1, 2, 4 and 8 (arguably zero, for the "no index" case, but the encoding suggests a different interpretation) exist, anything else cannot be encoded. The scale factor is not some arbitrary integer that is encoded as such, [the encoding](http://www.sandpile.org/x86/opc_sib.htm) only offers specific options to choose from.

Comment: The scale is a 2-bit shift count.  As you say, no-index is encoded by the code that would mean index=RSP.  That's why RSP can't be an index register.